# Sequence reordering to resolve data hazards in RISC-V assembly

Tags: computer-science, riscv

For the following sequence of RISC-V code, I am trying to identify the data hazards that cannot be resolved by data forwarding. Is it possible to overcome the hazards by reordering the code sequence? If yes, can anyone show the new sequence?

Here is my code:

```
loop: slli  s2, s1, 2
      add   s3, s2, s0
      lw    t0, 0(s3)
      add   t1, t2, t0
      sw    t1, 20(s3)
      addi  s1, s1, 1
      beq   s1, s5, loop
```

Comment: Please try to make your title as distinct to your specific question as possible -- a reader should be able to get a fairly good idea as to whether answers to someone else's question are likely to resolve _their own_ question (such that they don't need to ask another answer themselves) by reading the title alone. Consequently, a title that just describes the general topic of a question isn't particularly useful -- there's no end of distinct questions that could be titled "Systems Architecture", so the original title didn't do anything to identify the specific question at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Which data hazards can be resolved by forwarding is entirely dependent on the particular implementation of RISC-V architecture that you're using. I'll assume the traditional 5-stage RISC-V pipeline with forwarding presented in the Patterson & Hennessey textbooks, and take a stab at your question.

This pipeline has stages instruction fetch (IF), instruction decode (ID), execute (EX), memory (MEM), and writeback (WB). The execute stage computes values for register-register and register-immediate operations and computes addresses for memory (lw/sw) and control transfer (branch/jump) operations, and the memory stage reads data for lw and writes data for sw. Data could be forwarded from the end of the execute, memory, or writeback stages to the beginning of a previous stage for a subsequent instruction.

In the code snippet you included, there would be 5 data hazards:

(1) `slli s2, s1, 2` and `add s3, s2, s0`, for register `s2`

Here, register `s2` is written by `slli` and read by `add`. The new value is computed by the end of the EX stage of the first instruction and needed by the beginning of the EX stage of the next instruction, so it can be resolved with forwarding.

(2) `add s3, s2, s0` and `lw t0, 0(s3)` for register `s3`

Here, register `s3` is written by `add` and read by `lw`. The new value is computed by the end of the EX stage of the first instruction and needed by the beginning of the EX stage of the next instruction, so it can be resolved with forwarding.

(3) `lw t0, 0(s3)` and `add t1, t2, t0` for register `t0`

Here, register `t0` is written by `lw` and read by `add`. The new value is computed by the end of the MEM stage of the first instruction and needed by the beginning of the EX stage of the next instruction, so **it canNOT be resolved with forwarding**.

(4) `add t1, t2, t0` and `sw t1, 20(s3)` for register `t1`

Here, register `t1` is written by `add` and read by `sw`. The new value is computed by the end of the EX stage of the first instruction and needed by the beginning of the MEM stage of the next instruction, so it can be resolved with forwarding.

(5) `addi s1, s1, 1` and `beq s1, s5, loop` for register `s1`

Here, register `s1` is written by `addi` and read by `beq`. The new value is computed by the end of the EX stage of the first instruction. Usually for RISC-V pipelines without any optimizations for control hazards, for branch instructions, registers are compared during EX in parallel with the computation of program counter + offset to get the branch destination. The control hazard here is a separate issue, but the data hazard is resolvable by forwarding.

So of the 5 hazards, only one is not resolvable by data forwarding. Can it be resolved by instruction reordering? Yes. Take a look at `addi s1, s1, 1`. Before the `addi`, `s1` is not read or written by any instruction after the first `slli`. If we move that instruction, so the resulting code looks like this:

```
loop: slli  s2, s1, 2
      add   s3, s2, s0
      lw    t0, 0(s3)
      addi  s1, s1, 1
      add   t1, t2, t0
      sw    t1, 20(s3)
      beq   s1, s5, loop
```

This way, the `lw` instruction that retrieves the data to be written into `t0` will have completed the MEM stage by the time the new value of `t0` is needed by the `add t1, t2, t0` instruction.

With this reordering, all data hazards could be resolved with forwarding, and no stalls would be necessary.